# What exactly do I need to do to host a WCF service in IIS 7.0 using netTcpBinding?

Tags: wcf, iis-7, nettcpbinding

I've been trying for more than a week without any success at all, to host a very simple HelloWorld-like wcf service using netTcpBinding.

With http, everything is ok. I can access my service even from a remote machine. But with tcp problems arise.

I have performed all the steps I'm supposed to, in order to host my service in WAS:

- .Net 3.0 Features are enabled, including http and non-http Activation
- I have granted 'Network Service' and 'IIS_IUSRS' the following permissions to the folder containing the site:

  - Read & Execute
  - List Folder Contents
  - Read
- Opened de ports 8100 and 8086 in the firewall.
- At IIS Manager/ Actions / Bindings the following bindings are set up:

  - http 8100:*
  - net.tcp 8086:*
- At IIS Manager/ Manage Web Site / Advanced Settings, both, http and net.tcp protocols are enabled.

The original problem I had was that I was able to reach the service via http but when trying with tcp I got the following error:

**"The message could not be dispatched because de service at the endpoint addres 'net.tcp://myDomain/HelloWorld.Hello.svc' is unavailable for the protocol address.**"

I found a post in this site whose author had the same problem and It was solved by reinstalling .net 3.0 features. So I tryed that. I also tryed to reinstall IIS 7.0 just in case.
Now, the situation is worse than it was at the begining. If I configure an endpoint with tcpBinding in my Web.Config I can't even reach my service at it's http address using IE!! I get the following message:

**Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].**

The Web.Config file is as follows:

```
       name="HelloWorld.Hello">
       <host>
          <baseAddresses>
             <add baseAddress="http://myDomain:8100/HelloWorld/" />
         <add baseAddress="net.tcp://myDomain:8086/HelloWorld/" />
          </baseAddresses>
       </host>          

       <endpoint address=""
                 binding="wsHttpBinding"
                 contract="HelloWorld.IHello"
                 bindingConfiguration="httpInseguro">
       </endpoint>

       <endpoint address=""
                 binding="netTcpBinding"
                 contract="HelloWorld.IHello"
                 bindingConfiguration="netTcpInseguro">
       </endpoint>


       <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />

    </service>
 </services>

<bindings>

  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name ="httpInseguro">
      <security mode ="None" />
    </binding>        
  </wsHttpBinding>

  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name ="netTcpInseguro">
      <security mode ="None" />
    </binding>        
  </netTcpBinding>

</bindings>
```

and the .svc file is like this:

Could anyone please give me a clue about what's going on? I really don't know what else to do. This is being a real headacke becasuse using http binding is not an option.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of .NET are you running?

Comment: Hi John,

It's .net 3.5.

Regards.

Comment: I'm having the same trouble. What did you added to your config file to make it work?

Comment: Hi Luiz,

Unfortunatelly, we're not running owr service using netTcpBinding anymore since a few months ago, so I don't have the configuration file that finally worked at that time.
However, Marc's answer above helped at that time I recall.
One thing for sure, I had to check several sites on the internet to figure it out. I couldn't find the complete procedure in a single site.
Best wishes,

Gonzalo

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo,
I will continue looking and trying. I have already tried lots of different suggestions up to the time.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to enable the TCP hosting in WAS by calling `appcmd.exe`:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set site 
    "Default Web Site" -+bindings.[protocol='net.tcp',bindingInformation='*']
```

Check out the [MSDN documenation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731053.aspx) or Michele Leroux Bustamante's [article on this topic](http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0701041&page=6) - it contains all the info you'll need.

Marc

Comment: you can also do this via the IIS7 Gui. Go to your site -> edit bindings and add the net.tcp binding with the corresponding port:*

Comment: +1 from me @marc plus more if possible! I did notice that in my environment I needed to specify the binding information as '808:*' perhaps this should be edited into your answer? Also found that having the incorrect '*' broke things. I needed to remove it before this would work. Thanks again, saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

Thnak you for your answer and for the links. I'll check them.
I forgot to tell but I had already enable TCP hosting on was.
Someone suggested me to add this to the config file:

```
<endpoint address="mextcp" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
```

And now it's working ok.
Best regards,

Gonzalo